# Execute shell script on remote machine using ssh once the build is aborted in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using a freestyle jenkins project and wanted to execute a shell script on a remote host only when the build is aborted/failed . Is there any feature/plugins to support this requirement ?

I've used : ssh, ssh-agent and publish-over-ssh plugins , but can't see the option to 'execute the ssh commands to remote server' in 'Add post-build action' tab .

Also, I'm not sure how can I add execute the script only when the build is aborted .

Any help is most welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by using the **PostBuildScript** plugin .
It has the features which allows to execute the shell scripts over remote machine using ssh under 'Add post-build action' if the build was either 'Unstable|Failure|Not Built|Aborted'.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this make sure you have the Conditional BuildStep Plugin installed in Jenkins

In your Jenkins job configuration, go to "Add post-build action" and select "Conditional step (single)" from the dropdown

Set up the condition in the "Run?" field to check if the build result is either "ABORTED" or "FAILURE." ( which is appropriate to your case ) You can use the expression ${BUILD_STATUS == 'ABORTED' || BUILD_STATUS == 'FAILURE'}.

Inside the Conditional step, add the build step for executing the shell script on the remote host using SSH. Use the appropriate option based on your setup, like "Execute shell script on remote host using SSH."

Save the job configuration and trigger a build to test what you configured until now, what you should test is if the script is executed only when the build is aborted or failed.

**PS : Ensure your SSH key setup and remote execution configuration are correct for the plugins you're using.**

Comment: After installing that plugin, I could see 'Conditional step (single)' under 'Add build step' instead under 'Add post-build action' . Also, when I configured the job under 'Add build step', the conditional step didn't run when I manually aborted the build.